# How display a text in center of PieSlice and BarSet in qt quick application?

Tags: qt, charts, qml, qtquickcontrols2, qtcharts

I used charts in my qt quick controls 2 application.

```
ChartView {
    StackedBarSeries {
        BarSet
        {
            label: "not reviewed"
            color: "yellow"
            values: reviewCountInLevels.notReviewd                   
        }
    }
}
ChartView {
    PieSeries {
        PieSlice {
            label: "not reviewd"
            value:reviewCount.notReviewed
            color: "yellow"
            labelPosition: PieSlice.LabelInsideTangential
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display the value of `PieSlice` or `StackedBarSeries` in center ,can anyone show me how? the result must be like below

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: labelVisible: true; labelPosition: PieSlice.LabelInsideHorizontal;